# Ruby undefined method `errors' with associations has_many -> belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have reviewed the code from 200 times. Maybe I can help you find a wizard who breaks the whole. I create a room entry that is connected with the hotel but also with the account. I do not have any problems writing data. Until I do not pass data through validation. When the validation is also fulfilled, the data is saved, but when I do not want to meet their expectations, it is natural to flash errors, but unfortunately I can not find the error method.

undefined method `errors' for Room::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007ff8b2a36530

```
                            <% if @room.errors.full_messages.any? %>
                                <div class="error_explanation">
                                    <h2><%= t('other.errors', :count => @room.errors.full_messages.size) %></h2>
                                    <ul>
                                    <% @room.errors.full_messages.each do |error_message| %>
                                        <li><%= error_message  %></li>
                                    <% end %>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            <% end %>
```

**My controller**

```
def new
        @account = Account.find(current_user.account_id)
        @room = @account.rooms.new

        @hotels = @account.hotels.all

        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
            flash[:error] = "#{t 'alerts.Not_found'}"
            redirect_to(rooms_manages_path)
    end

    def create
        @account = Account.find(current_user.account_id)
        @room = @account.rooms

        @hotels = @account.hotels.all

        if @room.create(room_params).valid?
          flash[:success] = "#{t 'alerts.Is_save'}"
          redirect_to(rooms_manages_path)
        else
          flash[:warning] = "#{t 'alerts.If_save'}"
          render 'new'
        end

        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
            flash[:error] = "#{t 'alerts.Not_found'}"
            redirect_to(rooms_manages_path)
    end
```

**My model**

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :account
    belongs_to :hotel
    has_many :reservations

    mount_uploaders :images, ImagesroomUploader
    serialize :images, JSON # If you use SQLite, add this line.

    validates :name, presence: true

end

class Account < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :users, inverse_of: :account, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :hotels
    has_many :rooms
    has_many :offers
    has_many :reservations
    has_many :widgets
    has_many :accountsinvoices
    has_many :accountspayments

end
```

**My view**

```
<%= form_for(:room, :url => rooms_manages_create_path(), :html => {:id => "form"}) do |f| %>

                                <% if @room.errors.full_messages.any? %>
                                    <div class="error_explanation">
                                        <h2><%= t('other.errors', :count => @room.errors.full_messages.size) %></h2>
                                        <ul>
                                        <% @room.errors.full_messages.each do |error_message| %>
                                            <li><%= error_message  %></li>
                                        <% end %>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                <% end %>

                                <%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %>

                                <div class="text-left">
                                <%= submit_tag("#{t 'other.actions.save'}", class: 'btn btn-primary') %>
                                </div>

                                <% end %>
```

Comment: The error message tells you that `@room` is not a single model instance but a collection of model instances. But `errors` is only defined on a single model instance (for example `@room.first`)

Comment: @fl9 ok, so how to refer to errors in order to display them

Answer (score 2):

Your `create` action sets `@room` to a **collection**

```
@room = @account.rooms
```

hence your error message in the view. Instead, try

```
# some code ommitted ...
@room = @account.rooms.create(room_params)
@hotels = @account.hotels.all
if @room.valid?
# some code ommitted ...
```

Comment: hahaha I tried this way but apparently wrong ;-)
Thanks a lot and I wish you a nice, cheerful day

Comment: instead of @ room.valid? I used the @ room.save.valid method